# How does a mere mortal decipher "npm ERR! code ERESOLVE" output

Tags: npm

I'm trying to resolve npm dependency issues by installing the correct versions of things.  I don't want to use `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`.  I want to actually SOLVE the problem.  But the output is so opaque and hard to understand.

Is there a tool out there where I can plug this in and a get human-readable version?

Or does someone here know how to read this output and explain it to me?  Thanks!

```bash
> rm -rf ./node_modules ./.babel-cache; npm install

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mywebsite.com@5.2734.0
npm ERR! Found: @my-organization/brander@1.1.1-beta.7857
npm ERR! node_modules/@my-organization/brander
npm ERR!   @my-organization/brander@"^1.1.1-beta.7857" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @my-organization/brander@">=1.1.0-beta.0" from @my-organization/ui@0.14.1-beta.48
npm ERR! node_modules/@my-organization/ui
npm ERR!   @my-organization/ui@"^0.14.1-beta.48" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/myusername/.npm/_logs/2023-12-07T22_58_40_561Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/myusername/.npm/_logs/2023-12-07T22_58_40_561Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

`mywebsite.com@5.2734.0` uses `@my-organization/brander@1.1.1-beta.7857`
you installed exactly `@my-organization/brander@1.1.1-beta.7857`
because you write the range `@my-organization/brander@"^1.1.1-beta.7857"`

You get `@my-organization/brander` correct

You have set range `@my-organization/ui@"^0.14.1-beta.48"`
So you installed `@my-organization/ui@0.14.1-beta.48`
But `@my-organization/ui@0.14.1-beta.48` only peer `@my-organization/brander@">=1.1.0-beta.0"`

Problem could be `@my-organization/brander@">=1.1.0-beta.0"` may not infinite forward compatible
so `@my-organization/brander@"^1.1.1-beta.7857"` maybe too new for `@my-organization/ui@0.14.1-beta.48` to handle

you can try to upgrade the `@my-organization/ui@"^0.14.1-beta.48`
That exactly support `@my-organization/brander@"^1.1.1-beta.7857"`

I can't find your package online so I can't tell you exactly the version you should upgrade to.
But this is a reference of what similar thing you should look up to
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions

Hope this help